# Backbone.js single collection item view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view

I've recently started building my first Backbone.js project and am having a difficult time grasping how to handle "individual views" for single items.

If for example, I had a list of [todos](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/backbone) that were being displayed by a Backbone collection. If I wanted to have the application provide a link and view to an individual todo item, how would I go about that? Would I create a new type of collection and somehow filter the collection down by the id of an individual item? Where would this logic live? Within a router?

**Edit**

I've since updated my router as such:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var IndexListing = require('./indexlisting');
var BookView = require('./bookview');
var LibraryCollection = require('./library');

module.exports = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    '': 'allBooks',
    'book/:id': 'singleBook'
  },
  allBooks: function(){
    new IndexListing({
      el: '#main',
      collection: LibraryCollection
    }).render();
  },
  singleBook: function(bookID){
    console.log(bookID);
    new BookView({
      el: '#main',
      collection: LibraryCollection.get(bookID)
    }).render();
  }

});
```

The `bookID` is coming straight from my MongoDB ID and returns within the `console.log` but when I attempt to run this in the browser I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` which is referring to the line `collection: LibraryCollection.get(bookID)`

My LibraryCollection (./library) contains the following:

```
'use strict';

 var Backbone = require('backbone');
 var Book = require('./book');

 module.exports = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Book,
   url: '/api/library'
 });
```

Both of my endpoints for GET requests return the following:

*/api/library/*

```
[{"_id":"54a38070bdecad02c72a6ff4","name":"Book Name One"},{"_id":"54a38070bdecad02c72a6ff5","name":"Book Name Two"},{"_id":"54a38070bdecad02c72a6ff6","name":"Book Name Three"},{"_id":"54a38070bdecad02c72a6ff7","name":"Book Name Four"}]
```

*/api/library/54a38070bdecad02c72a6ff4*

```
{"_id":"54a38070bdecad02c72a6ff4","name":"Book Name One"}
```

**Edit no 2**

I've updated my router for `singleBook` as follows:

```
singleBook: function(id){
var lib = new LibraryCollection;
lib.fetch({
  success: function(){
    book = lib.get(id);
    new BookView({
      el: '#main',
      model: book
    }).render();
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend the codeschool backbone courses [here](https://www.codeschool.com/paths/javascript) for an intro to backbone.

You would have a collection of models (todos). Each todo would have its own view and would show the model data, i.e the todo description. You would probably want to have a wrapper view also known as a collection view that would have each view as a subview, but it might be better to leave that out while you're getting started.

With regards to the router logic, try and think of the functions in a router as controller actions (assuming you are familiar with MVC). There are a number of backbone extensions that create MVC controller-like functionality.

For your question you would create the link in the view when you render it with a template engine. A few engines that come to mind are Underscore, Handlebars and Mustache. A template might look like this:

```
<a href="/todos/{{ id }}">{{ description }}</a>
```

In this template we pass in the model and between the curly braces you can see we are trying to pull out the id and description of that model. Out model attributes might look like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    description: "Go shopping"
}
```

If you want to just get one model you need to make sure that the model has [urlRoot](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot) property set. Then you need to fetch the model like this:

```
var singleTodo = new Todo({id: 1});
singleTodo.fetch();
```

As I said before I would really recommend watching a number of good tutorials on backbone before you get too deep into your app. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean you're trying to navigate to a page that shows a single todo item? if yes the logic would live in the router

```
var TodosRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
   "todo": "allTodos"
   "todo/:todoId": "singleTodo"
   },
  allTodos: function() {
    // assume you have a todo listing view named TodoListing, extended from Backbone.View
    // which the view inside has the link to click and navigate to #todo/<todoId>
    var view = new TodoListing({
      el: $('body'),
      collection: YourTodosCollection
    }).render();
  },
  singleTodo: function(todoId) {
    // assume you have a todo single view named TodoView, extended from Backbone.View
    var view = new TodoView({
      el: $('body'),
      model: YourTodosCollection.get(todoId)
    }).render();
  }
});
```

#### update based on edit 2

Yes this would works but it will need to fetch the whole collection from the DB and then only get the single model to display, which might cost a lot of the network resource/ browser memory performance.

In my point of view is good to just pass the ID of the book to the BookView, and then we fetch single book from there (provided we have a REST GET call for the single book with ID as param).

```
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function () {...},
  initialize: function(option) {
    this.model.fetch(); // fetch only single book, with the bookId passed below
    //alternative - we do not pass the model option at below, we could parse the bookId from the router's since it will be part of param in URL eg: http://xxxx/book/:bookId, then we can do the below
    this.model = new BookModel({id: parsedFromRouter});
    this.model.fetch();
  }
});

new BookView({
  el: '#main',
  model: new BookModel({id: bookId}) 
}).render();
```

the fetch call should be async, so we might want to show some loading indicator and only render the view when the fetch done

```
this.model.fetch({
  success: function () { //call render }
})
```

Comment: So I'd perform a get on the collection?

Comment: Yes, with the condition that each of the model in your collection does has a valid Id property (usually the Id is null for a new model, and expecting the server-end to provide a new Id after saving the model via REST). the `get` on the collection is to get the model from the collection using the Id [backbone doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get)

Comment: I went ahead and attempted to implement your solution but ran into some issues. See edit above. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure thing. See above.

Comment: Lets try to export an instance  
     module.exports = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
       model: Book,
       url: '/api/library'
     })();... then fetch the collection before feeding it to the TodoListing / TodoView views...anyway the flow here is a little bit confusing..... supposely in the TodoView, you can just pass the ID of the todoId, then initiate a `Book` model and trigger the fetch after setting the ID.

Comment: one more thing, in the BookView, new BookView({
      el: '#main',
      collection: LibraryCollection.get(bookID)
    }).render(); ....the `collection` should be `model`

Comment: Since fetch isn't asynchronous I ended up having to put the collection.get(id) within the fetch success callback. See above as I believe I've gotten this to work correctly. Essentially the flow looks like I must first fetch the entire collection _before_ I can perform a get method to return an individual model. Is this typically how this is done?

Comment: why do you think the fetch isn't asyn? would you mind to tell me more? i haved updated based on your edit.